# How to test exceptions in mock unittests for non-deterministic functions?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, monkeypatching

I've a chain of functions in my library that looks like this, from `myfuncs.py`

```py
import copy
import random

def func_a(x, population=[0, 0, 123, 456, 789]):
    sum_x = 0
    for _ in range(x):
        pick = random.choice(population)
        if pick == 0: # Reset the sum.
            sum_x = 0
        else:
            sum_x += pick
    return {'input': sum_x}

def func_b(y):
    sum_x = func_a(y)['input']
    scale_x = sum_x * 1_00_000
    return {'a_input': sum_x, 'input': scale_x}


def func_c(z):
    bz = func_b(z)
    scale_x = bz['b_input'] = copy.deepcopy(bz['input'])
    bz['input']  = scale_x / (scale_x *2)**2
    return bz
```

Due to the randomness in `func_a`, the output of `fun_c` is non-deterministic. So sometimes when you do:

```
>>> func_c(12)
{'a_input': 1578, 'input': 1.5842839036755386e-09, 'b_input': 157800000}

>>> func_c(12)
{'a_input': 1947, 'input': 1.2840267077555213e-09, 'b_input': 194700000}

>>> func_c(12)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-121-dd3380e1c5ac> in <module>
----> 1 func_c(12)

<ipython-input-119-cc87d58b0001> in func_c(z)
     21     bz = func_b(z)
     22     scale_x = bz['b_input'] = copy.deepcopy(bz['input'])
---> 23     bz['input']  = scale_x / (scale_x *2)**2
     24     return bz

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Then I've modified `func_c` to catch the error and explain to users why `ZeroDivisionError` occurs, i.e.

```
def func_c(z):
    bz = func_b(z)
    scale_x = bz['b_input'] = copy.deepcopy(bz['input'])
    try:
        bz['input']  = scale_x / (scale_x *2)**2
    except ZeroDivisionError as e:
        raise Exception("You've lucked out, the pick from func_a gave you 0!")
    return bz
```

And the expected behavior that raises a `ZeroDivisionError` now shows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-123-4082b946f151> in func_c(z)
     23     try:
---> 24         bz['input']  = scale_x / (scale_x *2)**2
     25     except ZeroDivisionError as e:

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-dd3380e1c5ac> in <module>
----> 1 func_c(12)

<ipython-input-123-4082b946f151> in func_c(z)
     24         bz['input']  = scale_x / (scale_x *2)**2
     25     except ZeroDivisionError as e:
---> 26         raise Exception("You've lucked out, the pick from func_a gave you 0!")
     27     return bz

Exception: You've lucked out, the pick from func_a gave you 0!
```

I could test the `func_c` in a deterministic way to avoid the zero-division without iterating `func_c` multiple times and I've tried:

```
from mock import patch
from myfuncs import func_c

with patch("myfuncs.func_a", return_value={"input": 345}):
    assert func_c(12) == {'a_input': 345, 'input': 7.246376811594203e-09, 'b_input': 34500000}
```

And when I need to test the new exception, I don't want to arbitrarily iterate `func_c` such that I hit the exception, instead I want to mock the outputs from `func_a` directly to return the 0 value.

#### Q: How do I get the mock to catch the new exception without iterating multiple time through `func_c`?

I've tried this in my `testfuncs.py` file in the same directory as `myfuncs.py`:

```
from mock import patch
from myfuncs import func_c

with patch("myfuncs.func_a", return_value={"input": 0}):
    try:
        func_c(12)
    except Exception as e:
        assert str(e).startswith("You've lucked out")
```

###### Is how I'm checking the error message content the right way to check Exception in the mock test?

Comment: Are you using a test framework like `unittest` or `pytest`?  `unittest` has tools like `assertRaisesRegex()` to capture the exception and test the message matches a regex.  I think what you have looks good, though...  You mock out the random parts with known values to test specific cases.

Comment: I'm using `pytest` but good point on `unittest.TestCase` having an `assertRaisesRegex`!

Comment: Maybe I should do something like `assert re.match(..., e)`?

Comment: [`pytest.raises()` has a `match` arg](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference/reference.html#pytest.raises)

Comment: Awesome!! Please do add that as an answer, as well as the unittest point, hopefully that'll help others in the future =)

Comment: I realized when writing the answer that your test doesn't properly account for the case when `func_c` DOESN'T raise the exception when it should.

Comment: `ZeroDivisionError` is a symptom of a bigger problem: should `func_a` be allowed to return 0 in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - yes, to test non-deterministic function you should ideally mock all values that result in different scenarios. Packages like [hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can help you with that.

Few things that I noticed and would recommend to change

- You wrote you add `testfuncs.py` file to the same directory. It's good to have all tests under different directory (usually tests) so you have easier controll over which tests to run or can prepare a deployment package without tests.
- Althought I found the practice of checking logging messages in few places, I recommend to not do so. We don't expect to have tests fail after changing some typo in the message. In your case you could create your own exception and check if it's raised

```
class BadLuckException(Exception):
   def __init__(self):
       super().__init__("You've lucked out")

# test_som.py
with pytest.raises(BadLuckException):
    func_c(12)
```

Comment: That's a good idea to check for custom exceptions!

Answer (score 1):

What you have looks fine to me.  Unit tests usually break down and test each component in isolation and run through all the possible paths of execution.  Essentially, you want to make sure each line of code is run at least once to bring out any issues (instead of bringing out the issues when running in production).

With that said, there are tools in the various test suites to aid with common test cases.  One is `pytest.raises()` or unittest's `assertRaisesRegex` to assert that the code within that context 100% raises the exception you expect.

In your code, the test will still pass even if the exception isn't raised when it should fail.  You could fix that manually, but using the framework tools makes for easier to read and more concise code.

Comment: Good catch on the  missing out "`func_c` DOESN'T raise the exception when it should"!